# Symfony4 search within a PersistentCollection

Tags: symfony

I am strugling with my Symfony `PersistentCollection` - in a result set of query `findByOne()` executed on a repository. I need to find one or more elements by specific value within a `PersistentCollection`, ie withing other entity that has relation to the other.

I have a `RuleSet` entity with relation to `SrcFile` entity.
On a `RuleSetRepository` I call method `findOneBy(['id' => 1)` to find RuleSet ID=1. 
This returns an object `RuleSet` that has `srcFiles: PersistentCollection`.

Now what I need is to get specific object from that collection. I know there is a method `getIterator()` I can loop through all the result in the collection and make condition to find wher file.kind == 'master', but...

Is there any better way how to access/find/search within the PersistentCollection using buildin method?

```
//...
// dump of acctual result of 
dump($grsr->findOneBy(['id' => 1)]);

// dumped data (shortened version):
ProfileUController.php on line 118:
RuleSet {#1509 ▼
  -id: 1
  -srcFiles: PersistentCollection {#1507 ▼
    -snapshot: array:5 [ …5]
    -owner: RuleSet {#1509}
    -association: array:15 [ …15]
    -em: EntityManager {#975 …11}
    -backRefFieldName: "ruleset"
    -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#1230 …}
    -isDirty: false
    #collection: ArrayCollection {#1481 ▼
      -elements: array:5 [▼
        0 => SrcFile {#1573 ▶}
        1 => SrcFile {#1734 ▶}
        //...
      ]
    }
    #initialized: true
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the easiests way is a custom repository method for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Doctrine `Criteria`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections), which allows you to filter a `Collection`. It is smart enough to filter at the database level if the collection objects aren't in memory yet.

Here's a quick example:

```php
$ruleSet = $grsr->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);
$criteria = Criteria::create();
// Criteria to find SrcFiles where kind = 'master'
$criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('kind', 'master');
// return only the srcFiles matching criteria
$ruleSet->srcFiles->matching($criteria);
```

I prefer to create helper methods on my entity, as I think it's a little cleaner. This is up to you, but I would do something like this on the `RuleSet` entity:

```php
public function getMasterFiles()
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create();
    $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('kind', 'master'));
    // assuming you have a getter named getSrcFiles for the srcFiles association
    return $this->getSrcFiles()->matching($criteria);
}
```

Then you can do something like this (and you don't have to duplicate the code every time we need the master files):

```php
$ruleSet = $grsr->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);
$ruleSet->getMasterFiles();
```

**Update**

If you need to filter on nested collections, you have to use the `filter` method:

```php
public function getMasterFiles()
{
    return $this->getSrcFiles()->filter(function(SrcFile $srcFile) {
        // if callback returns true, then object is included in result
        return ($srcFile->getKind() === 'master' && $srcFile->getSrcSheet()->getName() === 'MainData');
    });
}
```

The `filter` method is more flexible, but it is always done on the objects after they are fetched from the database. This usually isn't a big deal, but can affect performance. The other option is a custom repository method, but I prefer to use helper methods on the entities. It feels more ORMish to me.

Comment: Perfect! This is what I am looking for. 
One more question - I did not mentioned it within my original post due keeping it as simple as possible but the srcFiles that are matching criteria have its own collection named srcSheets. 
How can I chain the query to find the file expr()->eq('kind', 'master') that are having srcSheet ...expr()->eq('name', 'MainData') ?

Comment: That gets more complicated. `Criteria` only supports properties directly on the association, so you can't filter on nested associations. To do this, you need to use the `filter` function, which works fine but will not filter at the SQL level, so it loads all objects into memory and filters in PHP. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Nice, this is something I can build on. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: there is a missing closing `)` in `$criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('kind', 'master');` can you please fix. I can not saved edits containing only a one letter change...